# Related Posts Images Don't Show Up Properly?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My related posts images don't show up properly! I want the image to show up completely and normally!

My related posts example page: https://softcroco.com/adobe-photoshop-7-0/

[image: Screenshot of grid of items with images]

I want my related posts images and titles be like the one in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of another grid of items with images]

My Code:

```php
<?php
// Related Posts.
if ( '1' === $schema_lite_relatedposts_section && empty( $disable_related_posts ) ) {
    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );

    if ( $categories ) {
        $category_ids = array();

        foreach ( $categories as $individual_category ) {
            $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
        }

        $args = array(
            'category__in' => $category_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'showposts'    => 6,
            'orderby'      => 'rand',
        );

        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<div class="related-posts"><div class="postauthor-top"><h3>' . __('Related Downloads:', 'schema-lite') . '</h3></div>';

            $j = 0;

            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

                $my_query->the_post();
                ?>
                <article class="post excerpt  <?php echo ( ++$j % 3 == 0 ) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" id="relatedfeatured-thumbnail">
'' ) ); ?>
```

```css
.related-posts article header { margin-bottom: -30px; }.related-posts .post.excerpt{margin-bottom: -85px;}.relatedfeatured-thumbnail img { width: 35px; height: 35px; margin-bottom: 0; }.relatedfeatured-thumbnail { float: left; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 8px; margin-top: 25px; }
```

I tried to change in CSS but nothing happens.

Comment: I can’t see where you output the featured image for each post.

Comment: It's the same as normal post featured image.

Comment: Where is the code that echos it out?